# Organize Checkboxes into Columns using Django Admin ModelForm

Tags: python, css, django, django-forms, django-admin

I am building an admin interface using Django 3.0 on top of a codebase I cannot change or overwrite any of the static files within. I have one select field, "states_incl", that uses the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget.

I have the code working successfully with updating and saving to the model, but I am wanting to organize these 50 checkboxes into 5x10 columns to limit the whitespace. Is it possible to achieve this inside of the Python code available for the admin.py? My snippets are below.

```
STATE_CHOICES = [('AK', 'AK'), ('AL', 'AL'), ('AR', 'AR'), ('AZ', 'AZ'), ('CA', 'CA'), ('CO', 'CO'), ('CT', 'CT'), ('DE', 'DE'), ('FL', 'FL'), ('GA', 'GA'), 
                ('HI', 'HI'), ('IA', 'IA'), ('ID', 'ID'), ('IL', 'IL'), ('IN', 'IN'), ('KS', 'KS'), ('KY', 'KY'), ('LA', 'LA'), ('MA', 'MA'), ('MD', 'MD'), 
                ('ME', 'ME'), ('MI', 'MI'), ('MN', 'MN'), ('MO', 'MO'), ('MS', 'MS'), ('MT', 'MT'), ('NC', 'NC'), ('ND', 'ND'), ('NE', 'NE'), ('NH', 'NH'), 
                ('NJ', 'NJ'), ('NM', 'NM'), ('NV', 'NV'), ('NY', 'NY'), ('OH', 'OH'), ('OK', 'OK'), ('OR', 'OR'), ('PA', 'PA'), ('RI', 'RI'), ('SC', 'SC'), 
                ('SD', 'SD'), ('TN', 'TN'), ('TX', 'TX'), ('UT', 'UT'), ('VA', 'VA'), ('VT', 'VT'), ('WA', 'WA'), ('WI', 'WI'), ('WV', 'WV'), ('WY', 'WY')]


class StateModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = States
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        states_incl = self.instance.states_incl
        if states_incl:
            states = states_incl.split(',')
            self.initial['states_incl'] = states

    states_incl = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=STATE_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=False)
```

I have used AI and googled to try and invoke a new .css file and use the attrs dict inside of CheckBoxSelectMultiple(), but nothing prompted the Admin page to change shape as expected.

I tried to put the class "checkbox-group" inside of the widget's "attrs" argument, and one of the css settings I tried is below along with the syntax used with the field assignment.

```
.checkbox-group input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```
states_incl = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=STATE_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'checkbox-group'}), required=False)
```